# Does every projection operator satisfy $\|Px\| \leq \|x\|\,$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, projection, idempotents

It's well known that an orthogonal projection satisfies $\|Px\|\leq\|x\|$.

Does this property hold for any general projection operator $P$, which is defined by $P^2=P$?

Comment: possible duplicate of [An example of an unbounded non-orthogonal projection in a Hilbert space](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1036260/an-example-of-an-unbounded-non-orthogonal-projection-in-a-hilbert-space)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The property does *not* hold.   For example, consider
$$
P = \pmatrix{1&0\\\alpha &0}
$$
for some $\alpha \neq 0$. Note that $P^2 = P$, but
$$
\left\|
\pmatrix{1&0\\\alpha &0} \pmatrix{1\\0}
\right\| = 
\left\| \pmatrix{1\\ \alpha} \right\| \geq
\left\| \pmatrix{1\\0} \right\|
$$

Comment: In fact, it can be shown that, if $P^2 = P$, then $\|Px\| \leq \|x\|$ for every $x$ if and only if $P$ is an orthogonal projection.

Comment: Thank you very much for a clear counterexample. Could you please explain to me why this property hold if and only if $P$ is an orthogonal projection?

Comment: @AnaUspekova see [my answer to that question here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1113520/81360).